# Set up Windows as a router using Powershell

Tags: nat, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-4.0

I'm running a virtual Windows 2012 R2 server which connects to a VPN. To share the access to this VPN with other Clients I've set up the Server using "Rouing and RAS". I used the NAT Option with the VPN NIC as public interface. This setup works just great.

For maintanance reasons I want to be able to configure exactly the same setup using Powershell. So I've fiddled arround with these [Network Address Translation (NAT) Cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn283352.aspx). But I can't get it to work. There aren't too many options with these Cmdlets - so I'm stuck already. Does anyone know a working tutorial, or has a working setup?

Thanks in advance.